# what's the difference between MATREAD and READ?

Tags: u2, universe

I need to understand the difference between MATREAD and  READ?  and please provide a simple example on where and how to use one.

Answer (score 9):

`READ` will read a record from disk and return it as a `Dynamic Array`.
`MATREAD` will read a record from disk and return it as a `Dimensioned Array`.

So, the real trick is to work out which array type is more applicable for your use case.

A `Dynamic Array` is essentially a string which uses certain byte markers to delimit each element (attribute/multivalue/subvalue). It is extremely easy to use, doesn't require upfront declaration or sizing. On the downside, if can be slower than a `Dimensioned Array`, mainly for large records or when you will be randomly retrieve attributes from the array - O(n log n) I think. Sequential access is optimized and is close to a `Dimensioned Arrays` speed.

A `Dimensioned Array` is essentially an array of strings (or `Dynamic Arrays` in the case of UniVerse). It reads each attribute into an array position. Each array position will then consist of a `Dynamic Array` for just the multivalue/subvalue positions of that attribute. `Dimensioned Arrays` required you to declare them and the number of array positions upfront. Depending on the flavor you have running, it will may cause a runtime error if you attempt to read in a record with more attributes than the array is sized for. On the flip side, it is O(1) to retrieve attributes from the array, regardless of your access pattern.

Comment: Dan - good explanation.  I think dynamic array access is O(n), however.  Whipped up a quick test and below are the results:

`Time to access position: 50000 = 0 ms.
Time to access position: 100000 = 1 ms.
Time to access position: 200000 = 3 ms.
Time to access position: 500000 = 8 ms.
Time to access position: 1000000 = 15 ms.
Time to access position: 5000000 = 76 ms.
Time to access position: 10000000 = 153 ms.`

The last couple examples show a pretty good linear progression.

Comment: Thanks Shawn - you are correct. A single access is O(n). I was thinking about accessing all elements, which is O(n) for dimensioned and O(n^2) for dynamic.

Comment: Dan - just wanted to add this is a great answer. Very direct and well informed.

Answer (score 2):

MATREADU bundles a MATPARSE with the READ.  These blow the attributes of a dynamic array into a dimensioned or fixed array.  This may be more efficient if you access the array frequently and more convenient if you are reading an I-type from a DICTionary.  READV reads only one array attribute.  Aim for clarity and optimize as required.

Here is an example in UniVerse of 4 lines producing the same output:

```
dim dimarr1(9), dimarr2(9)                                      
open 'VOC' else abort                                           
matread dimarr1 from 'OLDSTYLE' then print dimarr1(1) else abort
read dynarr from 'OLDSTYLE' then print dynarr<1> else abort     
matparse dimarr2 from dynarr ; print dimarr2(1)                 
readv dynatt from 'OLDSTYLE', 1 then print dynatt else abort    
end
```